# Load non-image file in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am running a piece of code on a website as a plugin. My Code runs in an iFrame on their website and I only can open the resources if I use an HTML tag, making a request doesn't work because of CORS.

```
const image = new window.Image();
image.src = url;
image.onload = ()=>{ // My Stuff}
```

the above works for all images, but for non-image files (like 3D files) I can't seem to find an alternative.

I tried Object tag but that just downloads the file.

Is there any way?

Comment: What would you do with such files on the Client anyways?

Comment: using Three.js open the file like an image, but it is 3D and can be interacted with.

Comment: Three.js is a Client-side 3D Library used to write other Client-side JavaScript. You may be able to just use the script tags from the page you are trying to "access", but there is no guarantee it will work like you want, as they could be using Server-side responses, which you wouldn't have access to anyways without CORS permission.

Comment: I don't have a problem Loading Three.js, I have a problem with loading the 3D file since I can't make a request to the host because of CORS. it only works using HTML tags, because it uses all the correct cookies. but I can't find an HTML tag like Image for non-image files.

Comment: "My Code runs in an iFrame on their website"? What does that mean? It works if you use an `<iframe src='theirsite.ext'></iframe>` on your site, or they are using an iframe to work with your code? You cannot evade CORS permissions.

Comment: it is a plugin, they open an <iframe> on their website and load a page from my website on it, hence the CORS problem.

Comment: You have to give permission to use your JavaScript then. In PHP that looks like `<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: absolutePathToYourSiteHere'); ?>`. So, yes you would have to change your page to a PHP page. Just change the extension to `.php` and slap that up-top. Then they can access your page with JavaScript like `const yourWindow = iframeElement.contentWindow; const someElement = yourWindow.document.getElementById('idHere');`.

Comment: that is not the problem, I can fully run my JS, the problem is I can't load some of the resources from their website because of CORS. it only works with HTML tags since it has all cookies.

Comment: They would have to give you CORS access.